# Remove first char of a field in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I got a kind of *selfmade* problem. I got a database where one field got his own porperty_type ("selfmade"...) and it is filled with a letter followed by a number.

What I need to do is, is to output the number in a "9 digit" version filled with zeros. (A value can be F234 as well as F12345678). For the filling I intend to use `myString.padLeft(8, '0')`

My problem is the starting letter. How can I get rid of it and convert the field into a string or int? All commands for java I found only work with strings or integers but not with such a mixed kind like I have. (deletecharat, substring etc.)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[]` operator:

```
assert 'F1234'[1..-1].padLeft(8,'0') == '00001234'
```

Comment: Oh, with that answer i feel kind of silly... works that way, thanks and sorry!